# HTML with Javascript - Apply grayscale to images in a table, then mouseover images to go back to colored version

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover, grayscale, onmouseout

I had a question about using the mouseover / mouseout event in javascript along with applying grayscale to a table. The question says that I must first making an image grid (table) all gray in html. Then I need to add javascript to the html so that when I mouse over the image, the image turns into a colored image, and when I mouse out from the image, the image reverts back into a gray image. **The problem said no CSS is allowed, so only using javascript and html, if possible.**
*Thank you so much in advance for the help, I really appreciate it!*

Here is some of my code below (the table images need to start from grayscale, then apply/remove the grayscale when using the mouseover event. So far the mouseover effect only works on the first image. And I also don't know how to apply a grayscale filter over the whole table first).

```js
function image_grayscale() {
  document.getElementById("image").style.filter = "grayscale(100%)";
}

function remove_grayscale() {
  document.getElementById("image").style.filter = "grayscale(0%)";
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <table border="3" align=center width="600" height="200">
    <tr style="width:1" ;style="height:10%" ; bgcolor="white">
      <td onmouseover="remove_grayscale()" onmouseout="image_grayscale()">
        <img id="image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1067/100/100" width="100" height="100" />
      </td>

      <td onmouseover="remove_grayscale()" onmouseout="image_grayscale()">
        <img id="image" style="grayscale" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1067/100/100" width="100" height="100" />
      </td>

      <td onmouseover="remove_grayscale()" onmouseout="image_grayscale()">
        <img id="image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1067/100/100" width="100" height="100" />
      </td>

      <td onmouseover="remove_grayscale()" onmouseout="image_grayscale()">
        <img id="image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1067/100/100" width="100" height="100" />
      </td>

      <td onmouseover="remove_grayscale()" onmouseout="image_grayscale()">
        <img id="image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1067/100/100" width="100" height="100" />
      </td>

      <td onmouseover="remove_grayscale()" onmouseout="image_grayscale()">
        <img id="image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1067/100/100" width="100" height="100" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: call the functions using `image_grayscale(this)` ... then have the functions take an argument ... eg. `function image_grayscale(el)` ... then apply the style to `el.style` etc though. you'll probably need `el.firstElementChild.style.` etc since your onxxx are on the td not the img for some reason

Comment: alternatively, use addEventListener to make the code modern and not have onxxxx attributes

Comment: "no CSS is allowed" what does that mean? You can't not use CSS in a web-browser.  Unless you're on a text-based browser like Lynx you'll always have CSS that will kick in. Modifying the `style` attribute of HTMLElements is just "another way" of manipulating CSS but it's still CSS. If you truly have to make it without CSS because you're not in a web browser, e.g in a node+JSDOM config, then you'd need to use canvases to do this, but you wouldn't get access to mouse events so... The proper way of doing this is to use CSS, let whoever asked you this question know that you know it is.

Comment: Hi all, for the no CSS part I think the assignment means that I can't use CSS to make the hover function, so I need to use the javascript onmouseover and onmouseout functions instead. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. An `id` attribute must be unique.
2. Don't clutter the HTML more than necessary. It should be really easy to read.
3. Use addEventListener instead of `onmouseover`.
4. Method names are usually written with kebabCase (see the new method I added).
5. Don't repeat code. Instead, refactor similar code into a new method.

```js
let table = document.getElementById('greyscaleTable')

table.addEventListener('mouseover', remove_grayscale);
table.addEventListener('mouseout', image_grayscale);

function image_grayscale(event) {
  let element = event.target;
  changeGrayscale('100%', element);
}

function remove_grayscale(event) {
  let element = event.target;
  changeGrayscale('0%', element);
}

function changeGrayscale(amount, element) {
  let isGrayscaleImage = element.classList.contains('grayscale');
  
  if (isGrayscaleImage) {
    element.style.filter = `grayscale(${amount})`;  
  }
}
```

```css
#greyscaleTable img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="greyscaleTable" class="table">
  <table border="3" align=center width="600" height="200">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img class="grayscale" style="filter: grayscale(100%)"  src="https://picsum.photos/id/1067/100/100" />
      </td>

      <td>
        <img class="grayscale" style="filter: grayscale(100%)" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1067/100/100" />
      </td>

      <td>
        <img class="grayscale" style="filter: grayscale(100%)" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1067/100/100"/>
      </td>

      <td>
        <img class="grayscale" style="filter: grayscale(100%)" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1067/100/100"/>
      </td>

      <td>
        <img class="grayscale" style="filter: grayscale(100%)" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1067/100/100" />
      </td>

      <td>
        <img class="grayscale" style="filter: grayscale(100%)" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1067/100/100" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestions! I'll be sure to try it out. I just had a question about the part where it uses css to write img { width height} etc. Did you put this inside the javascript or is this inside the main body of the code? I was trying to run it and it doesn't quite work, probably because I put the css in the wrong spot. Thanks!

Comment: I interpret the task as you weren't allowed to use CSS for the transition only. I wouldn't normally have inline style, like the filter, but instead place that code in a CSS selector (`.grayscale`). You can add the CSS as internal CSS through the `<style>` tag. Read on W3Schools for more information: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: See HTML as planks and nails, CSS as paint, and javascript as electricity and water, if I use a "build a house" metaphore. Try to separate these things as much as possible, hence no javascript or CSS in the HTML, and no CSS in javascript. This assignment is working against that, but I guess it's OK if it's just about learning.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally suggest the following:

```js
// define the function as a constant, using Arrow syntax;
// here we take the Event Object ('evt', passed from the (later)
// use of EventTarget.addEventListener(). From the Event-Object
// we retrieve the element to which the function was bound
// (evt.currentTarget), and update its CSSStyleDeclaration
// for the filter() function.
// We use a template-literal string (delimited with back-ticks
// to interpolate the JavaScript into the string, using the
// ${JavaScript here} notation.
// Based on the event-type we return the arguments of either
// 0 or 1; if the evt.type is exactly 'mouseenter' 0 is
// returned from the conditional operator, otherwise 1 is
// returned:
const toggleGrayscale = (evt) => evt.currentTarget.style.filter = `grayscale( ${evt.type === 'mouseenter' ? 0 : 1} )`,
  // here we retrieve a NodeList of all <img> elements within the document:
  images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

// we iterate over the NodeList of images to set them to
// grayscale(), initially:
images.forEach(
  (img) => img.style.filter = "grayscale(1)"
);

// we iterate again (as Array.prototype.forEach() has no
// return value; here we use EventTarget.addEventListener()
// to bind the toggleGrayscale function for both the 
// 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' events:
images.forEach(
  (img) => {
    img.addEventListener('mouseenter', toggleGrayscale)
    img.addEventListener('mouseleave', toggleGrayscale)
  });
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <!-- I removed the size/width attributes since they don't seem to be useful, use CSS;
             also duplicate ids are invalid, an id must be unique within the document:-->
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/animals">
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/architecture">
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/nature">
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people">
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/tech">
      </td>
  </table>
```

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).